Can't Select MRU Recent Files Item Twice
I have an application which uses a RibbonApplicationMenu which I've created using the example at WPF ObservableCollection not updating in ribbon view. This ⁬lists the most recently opened files. However it's not possible to select the same item twice. When an item is selected for the first time the selection is highlighted and the file opens using the XAML SelectionChanged event. However if selected again the selection is ignored. The only way around this seems to be to select another item then select the original one.
I suspect I need to set the selected item to null after opening but when I've tried adding a 'SelectedItem' event in the xaml and assigning null to it it doesn't work.
XAML
SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay}"

C#
public object SelectedValue
{
    get => selectedValue;
    set => SetProperty(ref selectedValue, null);
}

How can the original selected item be reselected to reopen the file?
Added:
Code in MySettings.cs relating to reading the MRU file names
private ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>> mostRecentFiles = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>> MostRecentFiles
{
    get => mostRecentFiles;
    set
    {
        mostRecentFiles = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MostRecentFiles)); // Not shown
    }
}

private KeyValuePair<string, string> selectedRecentFile;
public KeyValuePair<string, string> SelectedRecentFile
{
    get => selectedRecentFile;
    set
    {
        selectedRecentFile = value;
        OnSelectedMostRecentFileChanged(); // Not shown
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedRecentFile));
    }
}

Added: Relevant XAML MRU list code
<ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
    <!-- Additional commands (e.g. Open, New, Save...) removed -->
    <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent>
        <ribbon:RibbonGallery Name="RecentDocuments" CanUserFilter="False"
              SelectionChanged="MRUSelectionChanged"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRecentFile, Mode=TwoWay}"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory Header="Recent Documents"
                    HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource recentFilesTemplate}"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding MostRecentFiles}" DisplayMemberPath="Value">
                <ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemsPanel>
            </ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory>
        </ribbon:RibbonGallery>
    </ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent>
    <!-- Additional Code -->
    <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="RibbonApplicationMenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=RibbonApplicationMenu}, Path=DataContext.MyCommand}" />
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=RibbonApplicationMenu}, Path=SelectedItem}" />
        </Style>
    </ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu>


when I've tried adding a SelectedItem event in the xaml and assigning null to it it doesn't work Pls share what you tried.

The binding only updates the target/source when the value of the SelectedItem has changed. Clicking the item multiple times does not change anything.
After you have provided even more context, I revoke my previous suggestions. The final solution would have to rely on handling the PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp event instead of using the command.
You can associate a command with the items of the ribbon gallery (via the RibbonGaller.Command property), but this command would be only executed once - on item selection.
You could override the RibbonGalleryItem template, but this would break the native look and feel unless you completely replicate the original template.
Registering an event handler is much simpler. The key changes are the addition of the RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemContainerStyle to add the EventSetter to register the PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp event handler. The MyCommand is no longer needed in this context.
The solution could look as follows:
<Ribbon>
  <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
    <!-- Additional commands (e.g. Open, New, Save...) removed -->

    <RibbonApplicationMenu>
      <RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent>   
        <RibbonGallery Name="RecentDocuments"
                       CanUserFilter="False"
                       ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">  
          <RibbonGalleryCategory Header="Recent Documents"
                                 HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource recentFilesTemplate}"
                                 Background="Transparent"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding MostRecentFiles}" 
                                 DisplayMemberPath="Value">
            <RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemContainerStyle>
              <Style TargetType="RibbonGalleryItem">
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"
                             Handler="OnRibbonGalleryItemClicked" /> 
              </Style>  
            </RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemContainerStyle> 

            <RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                            IsItemsHost="True" />
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemsPanel>
          </RibbonGalleryCategory>
        </RibbonGallery>
      </RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent>

      <!-- Additional Code -->

    </RibbonApplicationMenu>
  </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
</Ribbon>

private void OnRibbonGalleryItemClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  var clickedRibbonGalleryItem = (RibbonGalleryItem)sender;

  // You may want to perform the following cast in the class that actually 
  // handles the file. This reduces the coupling. 
  // For example, changing the source collection type 
  // won't break this code if the cast is avoided. 
  // Instead, pass the clicked file entry as type 'object'
  // to the context that has the full knowledge of the type it handles 
  // and can gracefully perform the cast.
  // I only added this cast to demonstrate how the data 
  // can be extracted from the clicked container.
  var clickedMostRecentFilesEntry = (KeyValuePair<string, string>)clickedRibbonGalleryItem.Content;

  // TODO::From here you can invoke a command or a method of the class 
  // that is responsible for opening the file 
}


This didn't immediately solve the problem but I'll read some more on your idea and see if I can get it to work.

Why doesn't it solve your problem? Now clicking an item will always execute the desired operation.

I added your code to the xaml which also includes
<ribbon:RibbonWindow.DataContext>     <local:MySettings/>     </ribbon:RibbonWindow.DataContext>
In MySettings.cs I added
private string myCommand; public string MyCommand {     get => myCommand;     set => SetProperty(ref myCommand, value); }
MyCommand is read (as null) when I open the ribbon application menu but not when I select a file in the mru. I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

How do you initialize MyCommand? As MyCommand usually doesn't change I suggest making it a read-only property that you initialize from the constructor.

Also check the binding path.  Did I understood you correctly that the command is working? Or do you get null reference exception? How do you know that MyCommand returns NULL?

Sorry for my ignorance, could you explain "initialize from the constructor"? Do you mean  public MySettings(string myCommand)   {this.myCommand = myCommand;}?

I added a breakpoint at the get and set. Get returned null but set was never reached.

Yes, first the read-only property: public ICommand MyCommand { get; }. - Then the initialization from the constructor: public MySettings() => this.MyCommand = new SomeCommand();. - Of course, you can also pass the ICommand instance to the constructor as parameter. But the parameter type must be IComand and not string (like in your coment).

But in your previous comment that contained some XAML you showed how you instantiate MySettings as the DataContext. Instantiating a type in XAML using object notation is only possible via the default constructor. This means you (or the XAML engine) won't be able to call a parameterized constructor. Why do you pass the ICommand as constructor parameter, is there a special reason?

When I added public MySettings() => ...  the error appeared "Method must have a return type" so I added object. Also what goes in SomeCommand()?

No, a constructor doesn't have a return type. Doesn't the class is named MySettings?

Do you know about WPF commands? You must provide an ICommand implementation that the menu item then invokes (ICommand.Execute). First, please fix the constructor.

That was my typo on MySettings(). Fixed now. Not sure what goes in SomeCommand().

Ok. Do you know how to implement ICommand?

I'm fairly new to C# and still learning. Need to go out now, back on Monday. Thanks for your help.

I will post a small example. See you on Monday.

Your code didn't work. First the RelayCommand wasn't recognised. Found out I needed to install the CommunityToolkit.MVVM 8.0.0 package, the latest version caused errors installing. This produced errors on the RelayCommand arguments; argument 1:cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action', argument 2:cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Func'. I'm not sure what to use for the MyMenuItemDataModel. Currently I call a SelectionChanged event from the XAML RibbonGallery which passes the selected full filename in a KVP as e.NewValue.Key where the file is opened.

Harry, I told you to follow the link to copy the source code for the RelayCommand class. You don't have to install any library to make this work. And of course, the RelayCommand implementation you find in the library is not the same that Microsoft suggests in their article is different. They only sharethe same name as RelayCommand and DelegateCommand are the established names for such reusable ICommand implementations. I also wrote that. I consider the RelayCommand a helper class that you use in the proposed solution.

RelayCommand is not directly part of the solution as the ICommand can be any implementation of your choice. That's why I decided to not include the source code into the answer to reduce the complexity. Instead, I provided you with the link to the source code and asked you to copy it. If you had followed my instructions then you would have a working solution.

I don't write text to entertain you. I am writing it to answer your question and to help and guide you. It's part of the solution. Obviously only copying the code without reading the actual answer and annotations is not helpful.

Apologies for missing your explanation. I've now added the RelayCommand class though I still have a few build errors I'm trying to resolve. I do appreciate your time and patience.

Let me know if you have troubles fixing the RelayCommand related build errors.

The only remaining issues are with the references to MyMenuItemDataModel in both ExecuteMyCommand and CanExecuteMyCommand. I've implemented the MRU file list as ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>> MostRecentFiles. I've included the relevant code above. I tried changing the MyMenuItemDataModel to MostRecentFiles but it didn't work.

It depends what you want to have as command parameter. Is it the key value pair entry? You would have to adjust the CommandParameter binding accordingly.

After changing the MyMenuItemDataModel to KeyValuePair<string, string> I finally managed to build the app. For some reason it's still not calling ExecuteMyCommand and CanExecuteMyCommand although RelayCommand is called on starting the app and the RelayCommand arguments are correctly set but not when selecting a file to open. I'll need to do some more reading and checking of the C# and XAML code to see what I've done wrong or missed out. Thanks for your help in getting this far, it is much appreciated.

Are you saying that the command is invoked correctly when you click an item but the command parameter is wrong?

The command is not invoked at all when clicking an item in the MRU list. I've noticed a WPF error after running:
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SelectedItem' property not found on 'object' ... target element is 'RibbonApplicationMenuItem'.

Thanks. The error message was a piece of valuable information. If you check my example closely the binding source is the RibbonApplicationMenu and not the RibbonApplicationMenu__Item__. Changing the type should fix that error.

I'm not sure where you mean. I copied the XAML code exactly and not changed anything. I've added the XAML code above in case I've missed something.

Ok, now I understand the problem. I was still focused on the command. But your error is related to the SelectedItem.  I have updated the answer to show the final bindings that should fix all your errors and issues. I have a question: if the auxiliary pane contains the recent files list, then why don't you execute the command when an item of this list is clicked? Is this on purpose? Right now the command executes after clicking the main menu item after selecting an item from the auxiliary pane. Wouldn't it be more intuitive for the user to simply click the recent file item to open it?

Just a note, my example assumes that SelectedRecentFile property and the command are a member of MySettings.

The changes you suggested fixed the errors. Unfortunately on selecting a link for the second time nothing is invoked and the selection is still ignored. This can be reproduced by 1. Selecting a file in the MRU list, the selected file opens. 2. Make some changes to the file. 3. Select the currently selected file in the MRU list again expecting to overwrite the changes made. Nothing happens. I've added breakpoints at various places to confirm this. Could it be something to do with SelectionChanged="MRUSelectionChanged" event not being called the second time?

I'm unclear about your question. Clicking the main menu file item opens a dropdown similar to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/images/exper-printing-image10.png displaying the recent documents amongst other file options. Clicking a recent document (in the auxiliary pane) will open it.

I see. I was sure that the MyCommand that you assigned to the RibbonApplicationMenuItem via the ItemContainerStyle does not apply to the gallery pane (the RibbonGalleryItems). Your currently posted code does not execute anything when clicking on a gallery item.

I added breakpoints to ExecuteMyCommand and CanExecuteMyCommand and neither are hit on selecting a file from the MRU list.

I really wished you had shown all related code and not only snippets. I think we would have already found the solution. I would have had a much easier time to help you. In case you are executing file open from the event handler, then please read my post again to understand why the SelectionChanged event is not the appropriate event to handle. The main problem is that the side pane is not meant to be used the way you use it. It's meant to select items and not to execute commands. Please see my updated answer for a final solution

Let me know if you have any problems with the final solution.

I added your revised code and it now works as expected. Thank you for your time and patience and apologies for not providing all code as I wasn't sure what was relevant. I'll know next time.

Nice. I'm happy that we were able to solve your problem. Have a great time!
